# How to unit test a method that calling chains of private methods?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, jmock

```
    public void publicMethod() {
        privateMethod1();
        privateMethod2();
        privateMethod3();
        privateMethod4();
    }

    private void privateMethod4() {
        anotherPrivateMethodOrServiceCall();
        // ....
    }

    private void privateMethod3() {
        anotherPrivateMethodOrServiceCall();
        // ....
    }

    private void privateMethod2() {
        anotherPrivateMethodOrServiceCall();
        // ....
    }

    private void privateMethod1() {
        anotherPrivateMethodOrServiceCall();
        // ....
    }
```

Private method cannot be test individually without making it default(and that's a bit ugly).
If I test it from the public method, it always result in a super big mocking and assertion. It's a pain to maintain such big test cases. Any other good way or practice to deal with this problem? Thanks.

```
// long list of service mocking

@Test
public void testPublicMethod() {
    context.checking(new Expectations() {{
    // super long list of result mocking
    }});
    // ...
    // super long list of assertions
    assertEquals(....);
}
```

Comment: This is generally an indication that you're testing the wrong thing.  You shouldn't be testing that private methods are being called, you should be testing the calls to the external service (and those should be being made through a mocked service).

Comment: The publicMethod itself is a service call. It invokes lots of other service calls.

Comment: You may use reflection to invoke private method in test case

Answer (score 2):

I know very litle about Java or unit testing specifically in Java, so my observation here is a *purely general one* vis-a-vis Unit testing in general.

- It looks like your class is doing too much internally. If there's a reason why you need to make 4 private method calls as a result of a single public call, you could well be in the region of violating SRP (not that this rule isn't inviolate, but it's a good indicator of a design smell)
- Now we don't have too much context on what your "outer" class is doing, but given the information presented, perhaps you could consider instead refactoring the work done in each of these 4 private *methods* into 4 separate *classes*, which you can supply as dependencies to your main class; you then change your test approach to have multiple, smaller tests each of which just checks that a particular dependency was invoked

e.g your method names might look like

```
PublicMethod_InvokesService1(){}
PublicMethod_InvokesService2(){}
PublicMethod_InvokesService3(){}
PublicMethod_InvokesService4(){}
```

Which means you avoid having all those huge mock/ assert chains in a single method.

- You might think that this is naive because  - what about the order of operations - surely it gets too messy to make sure that the order of invocation is correct, what about passing return values from Method1 into Method 2 via Mocks, etc.
- In that case, if these services need to be invoked in a strict order, then you can also consider that instead of a flat list of dependencies, you really ought to use a hierarchy

i.e instead of

```
PublicClass depends on Service 1 (depends on Service2,3 and 4)
```

you have

```
PublicClass depends on Service 1 (depends on Service2 (depends on Service 3 (depends on Service 4))))
```

- This means that order of operations is N/A; each Service from the public on down only invokes a single dependency, meaning you don't need to worry about order. In fact you are already enforcing the logical order of operations structurally before you even write your public method.

Just my 2c.